# convert a single png file to jpg in vba

Tags: excel, vba, png, jpeg

As part of a larger VBA script I need to slim down image files before further processing. They are in PNG format and I can live with quite a lot of compression.

So I need a "png2jpg" procedure that take in a file location of the png and save a jpg version of the file at the same place and with the same name. My hope was that there was a native vba function that could do the transformation but I can´t find it (if it exists).

Comment: There are libraries available. Nothing native. https://imagemagick.org/script/ImageMagickObject.php is one example

Comment: You can convert them only by loading and exporting them as jpg.

Comment: What do you mean by "slim down"? Do you also decrease the images size? If yes, should this size be standard/the same?

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub ConveretPNGToJpg()
    Dim strFolder As String, strExpFld As String, fso As Object, file As Object, folderObj As Object
    Dim fila As Integer, ch As ChartObject, strExt As String, ws As Worksheet, boolOrigSize As Boolean
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strFolder = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" 'the folder where from the png files to be taken
    strExpFld = strFolder & "\TestJpg\" 'the folder where the jpg files will be exported
    Set folderObj = fso.GetFolder(strFolder)
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    boolOrigSize = True 'keep the pictures original size!

    Set ch = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(left:=200, width:=200, top:=80, height:=200)
    ch.Activate

    For Each file In folderObj.files
        strExt = fso.GetExtensionName(file)
        If strExt = "png" Then
            'if you need keeping the original size, the picture must be initialy added to the sheet and adjust the chart dimensions:
            If boolOrigSize Then
                Dim sh As Shape
                Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(file, True, True, 10, 10, -1, -1)
                With ch
                    ch.width = sh.width: ch.height = sh.height
                End With
                sh.CopyPicture: ch.Activate: ActiveChart.Paste: sh.Delete
            Else
                'fixed size:
                ch.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Fill.UserPicture (strFolder & file.Name)
            End If
            ch.Chart.Export fileName:=strExpFld & Replace(file.Name, strExt, "jpg"), FilterName:="JPEG"
        End If
    Next file
    ch.Delete
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: @user2523167 Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it work as you need?